# Root space decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Regarding the direct sum of vector spaces/algebras, the dimensions of the parts of the sum should equal the whole. With the root decomp, the cartan sub algebra seems to have a dimension as high as the big algebra and the root spaces have dim 1, summing to twice the dimension of the big algebra. This is because the size of the basis of the big algebra determines the number of roots which are the duel to the cartan sub algebra. Thus the cartan has the same dimension as the big algebra.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure? For example, with $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, the cartan subalgebra has dimension $1$, whereas the "big algebra" has dimension $3$. I think you'll find this is the same in general.

Comment: So does the cartan sub algebra always have dimension 1? I thought it didn't since it has a duel basis to the roots.

Comment: Nope. For example, for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ it has dimension $2$ (it is the diagonal matrices). Have a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/dimension-of-lie-algebra-according-to-root-system

Comment: Ok I kind of understood that. So for sl3 there are two other root spaces? If that's true sl3 has dim 4. Thank you for the help by the way.

Comment: $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ has dimension $8$. The Cartan sub algebra has dimension $2$, there are $3$ positive and $3$ negative roots

Comment: Ah, so the adj representation of the cartan elements on the "big algebra" are 8x8 diagonal matrices with 8 eigenvalues over the field with a double eigenvalue of zero?

Comment: That sounds good to me.

Comment: So the dimension of the cartan is 2, so its duel space, must be dim 2, but there are 3 positive roots. And roots can't be multiples of roots except for +/-. So the dimensions of the cartan and it's duel space don't match? Obviously I'm wrong, but I don't see where. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I'm a bit scratchy with this stuff.... Which is why I didn't post this all as an answer. Perhaps reask the question explaining what you now know?

Comment: Sorry about that. The definition of the duel basis of the Cartan sub-algebra is the set of roots or basis that span all other roots and all other elements of the duel space of the Cartan. Specifically, the basis is the positive roots and they span the negative roots. In the case of Sl3 you said the  dim of the Cartan was 2, but there were 3 positive roots, thus the duel basis of the Cartan is 3 while the Cartan's dim is 2, which doesn't make sense. Why is that, or what am I missing?

Comment: Still a bit rusty. But could it be that the definition depends on the number of *fundamental roots* - ie a basis for the root lattice. There are three positive roots but they are not linearly independent. However there are two fundamental roots

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you very much. And also, sorry for all the questions, but let's consider sl2. sl2 has 1 fundamental root, denoted alpha, and the basis of its cartan consists of diag(2,0,-2). If we pick another cartan element diag(4,0,-4), and apply positive alpha to it we should get 4. There is a relationship between alpha(diag(4,0,-4)) and the killing form (diag(2,0,-2),diag(4,0,-4)). I know you said your a bit rust, but can you explain why?

Comment: I'm a tad confused. What do you mean by applying $+\alpha$ to diag$(4,0,-4)$? The latter is an element in the *adjoint representation* of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ that corresponds to the *element* $2H = $ diag$(2,-2)$. The Killing form will be the trace of (diag(2,0,-2)diag(4,0,-4)) - i.e. $0$.

Comment: I read that there is a duality between the cartan sub-algebra and the algebra of roots. It said that these roots are linear functionals acting on elements of the cartan. It said that alpha(cartan element), which in the example I chose twice the basis of the cartan, is equal to the killing form of that cartan element and the basis of the cartan, respectively the trace (diag(2,0,-2)*diag(4,0,-4))=alpha(diag(4,0,-4)). I thought that alpha(cartan element) is equal to one of the eigenvalues of that cartan element.

Comment: Ah I miscalculated. The Killing form as you've written it will be 16. However, I believe we usually rescale the Killing form by the Coxeter number in order for things to work - for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ the Killing form is $\frac14 Tr(ad_x ad_y)$ which for your case is indeed $4$

Comment: I've just posed this question if you're interested http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889564/how-to-visualise-the-killing-form-of-a-lie-algebra

Comment: That makes sense, then they would be equal. I saw that question, thank you for your help and for asking that question. Keep me posted on what you find. I'll keep an on eye on that question too.

Comment: I will do - I'm supposed to be working on a project with more complicated Lie Algebra structures... but sometimes the basics slip away!!