# How to visualise the Killing form of a Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, we can define its Killing form $$K(x,y) = \mathrm{Tr}(ad_x\circ ad_y)$$for $x, y\in \mathfrak g$.

Whilst I understand that the Cartan decomposition $$\mathfrak g =\mathfrak h \oplus\left(\bigoplus_{\alpha\in R^+}(\mathfrak g_\alpha \oplus\mathfrak g_{-\alpha})\right)$$is orthogonal with respect to the Killing form, I'm still not really sure how to visualise the Killing form - by which I mean, intuitively, given $x, y\in \mathfrak g$, is there a good way to think about what the Killing form should be without pure calculation.

I'm also unsure what the reason for the definition is - what is the significance of the Trace and the adjoint action?

I would like to understand:

> How, given $x, y\in \mathfrak g$, can I visualise the Killing form?
> What is the reason behind the definition of the Killing form?

Comment: I seriously doubt here is any visualizing to be done...

Comment: As for the definition, it is a very natural one, actually. The trace of a field extension defines,  in exactly the same way, a bilinear form in that context which is quite useful, and that was quite in the air at the time people were studying this.

Comment: By visualise I mean is there a good way to think about it - we describe the Killing form in geometric terms such as being "orthogonal" and in some sense being an inner product. There should be a way to visualise that - for example, given two points, how can I see if they are orthogonal?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32554/why-the-killing-form.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I saw that question - it helps a lot with my second question, but not so much with my first